# How to keep AWS cli sync from copying files that are listed in the --exclude switch

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am uploading my photos from a Windows machine to an S3 bucket and each directory has a "Thumbs.db" file which I don't need to copy to the S3 bucket.

I have tried several variations of the `--exclude` switch to no avail. The documentation in both the help and online mentions using `--exclude` but there doesn't seem to be any exceptions and the Thumbs.db files keep getting uploaded. Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong?

`aws s3 sync "c:/users/myaccount/pictures" "s3://bucketname/pictures" --exclude "Thumbs.db*"`

But in each directory the "Thumbs.db" file keeps getting uploaded to the S3 bucket.

Comment: In addition to the answer it's worth using `--dryrun` if you want to test what's going to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--exclude "Thumbs.db*"` will exclude only root level `Thumbs.db.*` files. If they are in sub-folders, the sub-folders' names will be considered as part of the file key/name (e.g. `./a/b/Thumbs.db.info` which is not coveted by `"Thumbs.db*"`.

Thus you should try:

```
--exclude "*Thumbs.db*"
```